# Measuring the size of json response with groovy

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I have a dynamic json response, I'd like to measure the size of the list. Can you help?

[image]

Comment: resultInfo.keyName.size() - this should do it.

Comment: Can you please share the json that you are using?

Comment: There is a JsonCount Assertion: https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/assertions/reference/property/json-count.html

Answer (score 0):

I did it with JsonSlurper.

```
def json = context.expand( '${XXXXX#Response#$[\'resultInfo\'][\'XXXXXXXXXXX\']}' )
json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
def count  = json.search.size()
```